# loop gradient directions by clicking on a target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to loop all of the **eight** gradient directions by clicking on a target, like this:

```js
$('.targ').on('click', function() {
  let a = $(this).css('background').split(',')[0];
  console.log(a); // I need `to top` here
  if (a == 'to top') {
    a = 'to top right'
  } else if (a == 'to top right') {
    a = 'to right'
  } else if (a == 'to right') {
    a = 'to right bottom'
  }
  // and so on
  $(this).css('background', 'linear-gradient' + new_value);
});
```

```css
.targ {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='targ' style='background: linear-gradient(to top,red,yellow)'></div>
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Thomas - there is no problem, just enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `linear-gradient` value with `background-image`.

```js
$('.targ').on('click', function() {
  let direction = $(this).css('background-image').split(',')[0].slice(16);
  const gradientColors = $(this).css('background-image').split(',').slice(1);

  if (direction == 'to top') {
    direction = 'to top right'
  } else if (direction == 'to top right') {
    direction = 'to right'
  } else if (direction == 'to right') {
    direction = 'to right bottom'
  }

  $(this).css('background', 'linear-gradient(' + direction + ',' + gradientColors.join(','));
});
```

```css
.targ {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='targ' style='background: linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow)'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of background, you can get the style attribute.

```
$(this).attr('style')
```

It will return `"background: linear-gradient(to top,red,yellow)"`.

Then you use `.slice(28)` to cut out `"background: linear-gradient("` and `.split(',')[0]` to get the direction.

```
let a = $(this).attr('style').slice(28).split(',')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate it, make it simple:

```js
var c=0;

document.querySelector('.targ').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  e.target.style.setProperty('--d',(c+=90)+"deg");
})
```

```css
.targ {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--d,0deg),red,yellow)
}
```

```html
<div class='targ' style=''></div>
```